# IS there a way to get the same output without using "JOINS" and "WITH AS" approach

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have this insanely long query which gives me average group by brand for each years, months and weeks. This works fine but it's too long I want to know if there is a better way to do this and save some lines of code.
I am using multiple "With as" because I need to display averages by weeks, months, years. 
I need the average of the price of the elements composed by the triplet id_item || name_item || brand having price >=1.

```
WITH 
YEAR_2018 AS(
SELECT BRAND, AVG(PRICE)AVG_2018, 0 AS AVG_2019, 0 AS JAN, 0 AS FEB...
FROM
(SELECT ID_ITEM || NAME_ITEM || BRAND, SUM(PRICE), BRAND, 
FROM MY TABLE
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE) = 2018
GROUP BY ID_ITEM || NAME_ITEM || BRAND, BRAND)
GROUP BY BRAND)

YEAR_2019 AS(
SELECT BRAND, 0 AS AVG_2018, AVG(PRICE)AVG_2019, 0 AS JAN, 0 AS FEB...
FROM
(SELECT ID_ITEM || NAME_ITEM || BRAND, SUM(PRICE), BRAND, 
FROM MY TABLE
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE) = 2019
GROUP BY ID_ITEM || NAME_ITEM || BRAND, BRAND)
GROUP BY BRAND)

JAN_2019 AS(...)
...

SELECT YEAR_2018.BRAND, YEAR_2018 .AVG_2018, YEAR_2019.AVG_2019 ...
FROM YEAR_2018 LEFT JOIN YEAR_2019 ON YEAR_2018.BRAND = YEAR_2019.BRAND
LEFT JOIN JAN_2019 ON JAN_2019.BRAND = YEAR_2018.BRAND ...
```

```
BRAND  |   AVG_2018  |  AVG_2019  |  AVG_JAN  |  AVG_FEB | ...
==============
X            13.2        ...
-----------------
Y            25.6        ...
-----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results with a single result by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    brand, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_date) = 2018 THEN price END) AVG_2018,
    AVG(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_date) = 2019 THEN price END) AVG_2019,
    AVG(CASE WHEN TRUNC(my_date, 'mm') = TO_DATE('2018-01', 'yyyy-mm' THEN price END) THEN AVG_JAN_2018,
    AVG(CASE WHEN TRUNC(my_date, 'mm') = TO_DATE('2018-02', 'yyyy-mm' THEN price END) THEN AVG_FEB_2018,
    ....
FROM my_table
GROUP BY brand
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_date) IN (2018, 2019)
```

This technique takes advantage of the fact that `AVG()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: I already tried this but doesnt work because I have to add date to the main select and it becomes a filter in the triplet.

Comment: @carlos: here, the filtering on the date is applied via the conditional `CASE` in the `AVG()` function.

Comment: sorry, I meant the inner select*. To be able to use it in the conditional case I need to add 'date' to the inner select, and this messes up the filtered triplets I want to get the average from.